# Visual Studio 2017 can't connect to TFS 2017: LoadCachedCredentialsFormRegisterdProviders Method not found

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We are using **Visual Studio 2017 & TFS 2017**.

I have access to TFS web portal & TFS server (remote, share, db,..) & ... and everything works, but **I can't connect with Visual Studio** (***just in my pc***).

Error is:

> `Server 'http://tfs:8080/tfs' was not added.`
>
> `Method not found:`
>
> `'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssCredentials`
>
> `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssCredentials.LoadCachedCredentialsFromRegisteredProviders(System.Uri, Boolean ByRef)'.`

- Firewall is Off
- Antivirus is Disable
- Remove All Credentials in Credential Manager
- Check port access with telnet
- VS Version is 15.5.6
- TFS Version is 15.117.26714.0

**Any advice?**

[Screenshot](https://vgy.me/Vk67ET.png)

Comment: Seems it's the VS issue, try to repair VS, or reset user data : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /resetuserdata`. It that still not work, just try to install the [standalone Team Explorer 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/04/05/team-explorer-for-tfs-2017/), then try it again.

Comment: I tried all of that!!

Comment: I try VS 2015 and can be connected without problem!

Comment: So, it proves that it's an issue with the installation of  VS 2017. I tested on my side, can not reproduce this issue. You can check if this issue occurs on other machines, also try to uninstall it completely then reinstall.

Comment: I try that. Uninstall > Restart > Install.
I probably have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: I could not solve the problem. I had to reinstall windows.

Comment: The problem was resolved only after the installation of Windows!

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue and after hours and hours of searching on the Internet, I found a post suggesting to install the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient package from Nuget.  I added this package to the project that connected to the TFS server and the error went away.

I should note that I tried pretty much everything else I found, including reinstalling VS2017 on my original machine, then installing VS2017 on a fresh VM and getting the same exact error.